# Making a POST request to an external URL from a django + gunicorn + nginx setup

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am sending a post request from a method inside a web application running on django+nginx+gunicorn. I have no issues receiving 200 response from the same code when executed on django's own server (using runserver).

```
try:
    response = requests.post(post_url, data=some_data)
    if response.status_code == OK and response.content == '':
        logger.info("Request successful")
    else:
        logger.info("Request failed with response({}): {}".format(response.status_code, response.content))
        return response.status_code == OK and response.content == ''
except requests.RequestException as e:
    logger.info("Request failed with exception: {}".format(e.message))
    return False
```

I checked the server logs at post_url, it is indeed returning 200 response with this data. However, when I run the app behind gunicorn and nginx, I am not able to receive the response, (however the request is being sent). The code gets stuck at the first line after the try block, and gunicorn worker times out (after 30 seconds).

This is the apache server log at the post_url:

```
[14/Sep/2016:13:19:20 +0000] "POST POST_URL_PATH HTTP/1.0" 200 295 "-" "python-requests/2.9.1"
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention, this request takes less than a second to execute, so it is not a timeout issue. Something is wrong with the configuration? I have the standard nginx+gunicorn setup, where gunicorn is set as the proxy_pass in nginx. I am guessing since I am behind a nginx proxy, should I be doing something different while sending a post request from the application?

Comment: As you provide some useful information for diagnosis, I think you can have {} types of error here :

- it seems that you can achieve the http request but not get the result. First of all, checkout your firewall (likely be `iptables -L` command and see if there is a rule about port 80 on your `INPUT` table).
- is your request a https request to a non trusted server?
- have you tried to reach another server?

Comment: How many gunicorn workers do you have?

Comment: @artragis I can successfully execute the request using the django shell. I can run the same code in a python script without any issues on the same machine.

Comment: @VBart I have not set any number which means it's 1 by default. To complete this request, another request is sent back to the server...which makes me think will having more workers solve this problem? Yes it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my gunicorn settings, setting `workers=2` solved this issue.

When I was sending a request to the external URL, the external application would send a request back. This new request would occupy the one and only worker in the application. The original request that I sent out is workerless, and so it get's stuck.
With 2 workers, I am able to simultaneously send out a request and receive another request.

Answer (score 0):

You could have issues with Nginx, where the problem could be `nginx request entity too large`. If you sending too large data to the server, Nginx might reject the request. We had issues with Nginx causing problem when we were trying to upload too big image. We also using nginx + gunicorn with django. So I am suspecting. this might be the same issue.

Comment: No, I am just sending a small python object with some data, nothing too big. Anyway I can debug this?

Comment: Also, the request is being sent, I am not receiving the response, that's all

Answer (score -2):

This is a gunicorn timeout issue. You can increase the timeout of gunicorn by specifying the additional flag `--timeout 60` in the command you're using to execute gunicorn. Of course, you can customise the timeout length depending on your needs. The argument is in seconds.

Comment: This is not a timeout issue. Without gunicorn, the post request takes less than a second to finish.